# Mirror screen from Mac to another Mac running old OS

Tags: macos, mirroring, macos-highsierra, screencasts, macos-ventura

I have an very old Mac Mini which runs High Sierra OS. I connect it to my HDTV. Now I also have a Mac book which runs the latest Ventura. I want to cast media from my Mac book to the Mac mini so that I can watch the media on my TV. (The media app that I play cannot run on High Sierra.)

I cannot use Air Play to cast to the Mac Mini because it's not available for High Sierra.

What's the other best alternative for me?

Answer (score 2):

Use [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) on the Mini.
In a situation like this, it's far simpler to 'pull' from the older Mac than try to 'push' from the newer.

All you need do is set your MacBook to share the media drive. System Preferences > Sharing. Share your Media folder to an account you can allow to connect.

Once shared, then from Finder on the Mini, go to the Go Menu, Network & choose the shared media drive. You may have to start from the top level on the computer & 'drill down' first time, but it should appear in the list as a shared drive once connection has been previously established.

Find your file on the remote Mac & just drag directly into VLC's playlist window. It won't copy it, it will just play it from where it is - so you have to make sure your Macbook doesn't go to sleep while it's playing. VLC will keep the Mac it's playing on awake, but it can't also keep the remote server awake.
Tap spacebar [Play].
Movie on demand, no 'casting' required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The media that I want to play is not a file. It's a special app that can only run on newer version of OSX.

Comment: Then you really should have put that in your question… which would have saved both of us wasting our time.

Comment: Yes, I did put it in my question. There's a sentence which says "(The media app that I play cannot run on High Sierra.)"

Comment: No, that doesn't tell me. That just tells me you could probably just play the media on something else.